# Vectorize a For Statement - Zeros In A Diagonal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

Want to replace a Python 'for' loop with a vectorized comprehension statement to replace the left diagonal in a pandas `DataFrame` with zeroes.

The `dataframe` is instantiated using a standard `numpy.random.randint()` method.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,100, 100).reshape(10, -1))
```

I tried to apply a lambda function that locates/replaces the diagonal cells using the `df.iloc[]` method. Was expecting the left diagonal to be replaced with zeroes.

```
df = df.apply(lambda i : [df.iloc[i, i] * 0 for i in range(df.shape[0])])
```

The result yields an entire `DataFrame` loaded with zeroes.  Need help on how to write the lambda function since an assignment is not allowed in the lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `iloc` you won't get a vectorized function since you're essentially iterating over indices.

What you should do instead is to use NumPy's own `fill_diagonal()` method

```
arr = np.random.randint(1,100, 100).reshape(10, -1)
np.fill_diagonal(arr, 0)
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
```

Comment: I found the Numpy fill_diagonal method earlier today - good timing.  Thanks for the help.  Will use it rather than an iterative method.